# Regular expression limit string size

Tags: regex

How to limit string size for this regular expression?

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

I just need to add the quantifier `{3,16}`.

Comment: Can you add an example string and how you are testing it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sprinkle in some [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to test for the total length of the string by adding

```
(?=.{3,16}$)
```

at the start of the regex. The final regex is then:

```
/^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:_[a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

`[\w\d]{2,18}`

\w: matches a-z, A-Z, and underscores.
\d: matches 0-9 numbers.
2: Minium two characters required.
18: Maximum allowed characters 18.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

`/^[a-z](?:[a-z\d]|_(?!_)){1,14}[a-z\d]$/`

or

`/^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:_[a-z\d]+)*$/`