# limiting the filtering character in regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex in which I want to filter number with length 8-14 only. There are multiple `|` operations, so do I need to put limit in each or operations or any common solution can work for entire regex?

Here is my regex (matching UK numbers with various code. I need to consider some exploits, so please dont mind of it's length) :

```
$pattern = '/^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
```

Just adding

```
^\d{8-14}(adding above regex)?$
```

is correct?

please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly are you trying to match with that giant expression?

Comment: If you are trying to block an exploit while allowing valid phone numbers, there are cleaner ways to do that. Those ways will generally have more false positives (being more permissive), but can still prevent program exploitation.

Comment: thanks @merlin2011, let me know any reference you have. But as this regex works fine for me, I want to limit in this regex also

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197636/391161), I believe it suffices to prefix your expression with a positive lookahead specifying the length restrictions.

```
^(?=.{8,14})b$(adding above regex)
```

Comment: ok, this works http://regex101.com/r/vD2kY5, but it filters if number length is greater then 14 chracters