# Particular substring length in regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to check, if given string is in this format:

1. Substring of `\w` chars can be delimited (not start or end) by , `-` or `.`. And there can be more than 2 delimiters. For example `weerwer`, `as-sas.a` are valid. `-assa`, `a-s a-s`, `asd@d` are not. For that I use `^\w+([ .-]\w+){0,2}$`. Seems to work.
2. Whole string, that matches regexp above, I want to restrict to length of 8. For example `asd`, `asd-asd` are valid. `asd-asd-asd` is not. And that is my question. How to do that?
3. This is only in case, the solution depends also in another restriction I need. I need the substrings passed the above two to be able to be delimited by `/`. For example `asd-asd/asd.asd/asdasd/asd asd/aaaaaa` is valid. Pretty much same pattern as in 1. but not restricted to number of delimiters. I put it here only in case the 2. depends on it.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197549/regular-expression-limit-string-size) may be the answer to #2

Comment: Ok... seems to work. But can you explain why there is `(?=.**...**$)` operator instead of default look-ahead `(?=**...**)`. Why there is `.` before and `$` after expression?

Comment: The `.` matches any character and the `$` just means that it must be the end of the string. Just like you were using in #1.

Comment: Oh I get it now... I was was thinking about it completely wrong... Important is to note that it doe's not match any of characters. It only looks ahead. The current position after the lookahead is still the beginning of the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close it here, I'm posting solution based on @sareed`s comment. Thank you.

I changed some things...
1. `\w` was changed to alphabetic and decimal numbers. Also `_` delimiter was added.
2. Length of substring above was restricted to 16.
3. Number of `/` delimiters was restricted to 6.

Pattern:
`\A(?=.{1,16}(\z|/))(((\p{Alphabetic}|\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal})+)([\. _-]((\p{Alphabetic}|\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal})+)){0,2})(/(?=.{1,16}(\z|/))(((\p{Alphabetic}|\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal})+)([\. _-]((\p{Alphabetic}|\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal})+)){0,2})){0,6}\z`

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but should work:

```
/^((?=[^/]{1,8}(\/|$))\w+([ .\-]\w+)*)(\/(?=[^/]{1,8}(\/|$))\w+([ .\-]\w+)*)*$/
```